# C# SOAP - прочитать полученный массив

Tags: c#, .net

Пытаюсь тут работать с SOAP.

**1. Добивил Add reference...**

**2. Добавил ссылку на wsdl**

Проблема в том что если ТИП получаемых данных string, то все ок, я сразу получаю при вызове результат в переменную. И могу ее отобразить тем же message, но некоторые получаемые данные которые я вообще не пойму как отображать ?

**Пример 1:**

```
var bbb = response.data.count; // получаем кол-во
```

Обьект count (содежит пояснения)

> public string **count** { set; get; }

**Пример 2:**

```
var bbb = aaa.data.contacts; // получаем массив контактов
```

Обьект **contacts** (содежит пояснения)

> public
>   WindowsFormsApplication1.ServiceReference1.Contacts_List_Contact[]
>   contacts { set; get; }

Вопрос, как вытянуть данные из второго примера ? Так как проблема именно в понимании происходящего с примером 2, то есть если мы должны получить массив данных, то с ним дальше нужно как-то работать если это конечно массив.

Comment: Вы не знаете как работать с массивами?

Comment: Знаю, спасибо, ошибку нашел, просто из-за однотипных называний переменный попутал значение и массив местами при выводе в бокс.